# Why attribute app:endIconMode is not found in TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, androidx, android-textinputlayout

Hello I am creating an app with the androidx libraries but when I am trying to add a toggle to show or hide the password in an TextInputEditText with the app:endIconMode attribute I am getting the error error: attribute endIconMode not found.

This is my TextInputLayout and TextInputEditText

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password_text_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="password"
            app:endIconMode="password_toggle"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_text_input_layout"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/password_text_input_edit_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Also these are my dependencies in gradle

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha01'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

I am not sure what i am missing, maybe a dependency? As far as i read in the documentation no extra dependency besides the material one is required.

Thanks

Comment: this should work as per the older version, no need to import alpha app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"

Comment: @RomanGherta this should be the answer honestly. Worked awesomely for me without having to import anything new

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As per the [Material Design Components release notes](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases):

> 1.1.0-alpha04
>
> - Adding support for a custom end icon for the TextInputLayout. ([5685941](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/56859415e88224b9fa039f641eaaf7953a699e5d))

Therefore you must change your dependency to at least `1.1.0-alpha04`, not the `1.0.0` you are using:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha04'
```

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but support for the `app:endIconMode` attribute was actually introduced in this commit: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/4c2e9c40040d1aa151f0534b21e3045dc2ccb788

Answer (score 0):

use

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'
```

or goto [link](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#com.google.android.material:material)